# Does this code leak if use of function relace1() doesn't delete memory allocated by cc?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I think this code leaks, unless outside replace1() somebody deletes the memory allocated by cc = new[....], can you confirm??

```
char* replace1(char *c){
    if(c == NULL) return NULL;
    int len = strlen(c);
    if(len == 0) return NULL;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if(c[i] == ' ')
            ++cnt;
    }
    char *cc = new char[len+2*cnt+1];
    int p = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        if(c[i] == ' ')
        {
            cc[p] = '%';
            cc[p+1] = '2';
            cc[p+2] = '0';
            p += 3;
        }
        else
        {
            cc[p] = c[i];
            ++p;
        }
    }
    cc[p] = '\0';
    return cc;
}
```

Comment: A bad practice to return allocated memory - you might use unique_ptr (shared_ptr) instead

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: A bad practice might be to work with allocated memory using *naked pointers*, as opposed to using `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. There's nothing wrong with *returning* allocated memory per se. One can also point out that the question is only nominatively C++. It makes sense as a C question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function passes the pointer to the allocated memory back to the calling code. It passes the *ownership* of this memory to the caller. Which means that the function does not leak, assuming that the calling code receives the pointer and keeps track of it (and eventually deallocates the memory).

In other words there's nothing to suspect a leak in this code. From the memory leak prevention perspective there's nothing wrong with this code.

If your program leaks this memory, it is the calling code's fault, not this function's fault.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't leak, per se, but you leave it for the caller of `replace1()` to `delete[]` that memory, or else it will be leaked.

Answer (score 0):

No, this code doesn't leak - it returns the resource. Everything is OK.

As a part of documentation for this function should be something like - *returns dynamically allocated memory; caller should free the result*.

If someone outside does not free the resource, then it will be leak, but in outside code, not in this function.